# Normal p-subgroup and maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime s.t. $p\big||G|$, and let $P$ be a normal p-subgroup of $G$, with $|P|=p^m$. I want to prove the following:

> If $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, then $P\leq M$ or $[G:M]=p^k$, with $k\leq m$.

What I got so far:

If $M$ happens to be a p-subgroup then it clearly follows that $P\leq M$, so lets suppose $M$ is not a p-subgroup. Now, $P$ is normal in $MP$ and $P\cap M$ normal in $P$ we can apply the second isomorphism theorem and get that $[MP:P]=[P:P\cap M]$. And got stucked here, can't see how relate this last result with $|P|$ and $[G:M]$ to get that $[G:M]=p^k$, with $k\leq m$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $ M $ is maximal in $ G $, then $ MP = M $ or $ MP = G $. In the former case, $ P \leq M $; and you almost solved the latter case already... (you probably meant $ [M : P \cap M] $ and not $ [P : P \cap M] $.)

Comment: Oh I see, hehe. Thanks!

Comment: Note: To apply the second isomorphism theorem we need to show before that $M$ is normal in $G$